# CPU impact of switching databases (using "USE db;") at high rate in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

Before each query, my web application will need to switch to a relevant database. In total, there are tens of DB requests during each session.

Does anyone know if issuing `USE db;` many times in the same session will have any significant CPU overhead?

Comment: Why don't you simply try and measure it? (My guess is that it's negligible, as in REALLY neglible). Also: what if it's not? Do you have an alternative? It's not as if there's another way to select the data from another DB. So whatever the outcome, you're gonna have to use the `use db;` statement anyway.

Comment: Well, one alternative could be to maintain a (possibly persistent) connection per database and switch between connections in your program. Whether it's a good solution depends on the exact use case.

Comment: @marekful Ah, ofcourse, that would be an option. Didn't consider that, but it does, indeed, depend on the use case.

Comment: Sure you can always just throw more hardware at the problem, that always wins right ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I dug into the source code, and found a [mysql_change_db function](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/sql_db.cc#L1461) which I suspect implements this functionality. The comment there gives some idea of the possible overhead: before switching some internal pointers around, there are some sanity and security checks. How optimised those checks are, I have no idea, though.

Comment: @IMSoP `mysql_change_db()` will use `thd->set_db` but now I want to see if there is an implementation of `USE` or if it persists some open state ... Thanks for this rabbit hole.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. As for question of @marekful: I need to make JOINs between the DBs, that's the reason two connections is not an option.

Comment: The reason I need this switch is because that is a replicated database, and I create a lot of temporary tables, their `CREATE` statements get replicated. I want to switch to non-replicated DB before I create a temporary table, and switch to main DB for the rest of the queries.